# Why QSpinBox get focus when focusPolicy = NoFocus

Tags: qt, qt5, qspinbox

Why QSpinBox receives focus at pressed `Shift + Tab`? How to fix?
Example:

1. Create a form as in picture 1.
2. Set spinBox_2 and pushButton_2 `focusPolicy = NoFocus`
3. Start, and try to press `Tab` several times, and to press `Shift+Tab`.
4. We see that spinBox_2 get focus.

OC: windows 10. Qt 5.12.3.

[image: focusPolicy = NoFocus]

[image: err]

[image: no focus]

in *.ui file
**mainwindow.ui**

```
     <widget class="QSpinBox" name="spinBox_2">
      <property name="focusPolicy">
       <enum>Qt::NoFocus</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
      <property name="focusPolicy">
       <enum>Qt::NoFocus</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
```

Comment: Tried with Qt 5.12 on Windows, I do not have this issue. Which Qt version and OS are you using?

Comment: OC: windows 10. Qt 5.12.3

Comment: My bad, I was able to reproduce it, very weird. Also in my case, when pressing Shift Tab, the QPushButton does not get focus.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question "Why?", it's because it is a bug.

If you have time you can file a bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/

Answer (score 0):

Tried to set the **tab order** to not to letting **spinBox_2** selected?

See [Qt Designer's Tab Order Editing Mode](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/designer-tab-order.html)

Comment: Maybe you can set the focusPolicy = ClickFocus?